# Is there a method/interface specific for an attribute in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

Is there any way to have a method which processes the attributes and returns the desired value in python?
Below is the example of what i want to achieve.

```
   class Foo():

        self.a = '123'
        self.b = '234'

        def hex_value(self,attribute): # method for attribute.
            return hex(attribute)


    if __name__=="__main__":
        obj = Foo()
        print(obj.a.hex) # should give hex value of 'a' by simply using dot operator.
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel a little dirty by hacking someting like this together, but you could use some kind of proxy class to do this:

```
class Proxy():
    def __init__(self, value, parent):
        self.value = value
        self.parent = parent

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self.parent.__getattribute__(attr + '_value')(self.value)

class Foo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = '123'
        self.b = '234'
        self.c = 'foo_Bar'

    def hex_value(self,attribute):
        return hex(int(attribute))

    def repeated_value(self,attribute):
        return attribute + " " + attribute + " " + attribute

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if not attr.endswith('_value') and not attr.startswith('__'):
            return Proxy(super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(attr), self)
        return super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(attr)

if __name__=="__main__":
    obj = Foo()
    print(obj.a.hex) # should give hex value of 'a' by simply using dot operator.
    print(obj.c.repeated) # prints 'foo_Bar foo_Bar foo_Bar'
```

The idea is that everything that you access in `Foo` is wrapped in a proxy. And everything you access in the proxy that's not avaiable is called on the proxy's creator (with an '_value' added) instead.

But just because you can doesn't mean you should.